# How can I use a link in string to translate at Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, php, link, inline-translations

In Magento 1 I use this code:

```
<?php echo $this->__('some <a href="%s">text here</a>', Mage::getUrl('some/url/here')); ?>
```

How can I use in Magento 2?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your solution might look something like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo $block->escapeUrl($this->getBaseUrl().'customer/address/');?>">
   <?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Street Address %1', $_i)); ?>
</a>
```

All URLs and translated content should be escaped to prevent XSS. Also, HTML tags shouldn't be translated.

Also, you can wrap this code by an own method.

Comment: can we use %s instead of %1?

Answer (score 10):

HTML code should not be used directly in a translation string, instead use a placeholder (i.e. `%1`) to represent it, and put it's value in a subsequent parameter to the translation method.

```
<?= __('some %1text here%2', '<a href="' . $block->getUrl('some/url/here') .'">', '</a>') ?>
```

The Magento core team uses this approach throughout their code base.

For example in...

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list/toolbar/amount.phtml

Comment: I don't agree that **HTML code should not be used directly in a translation string**. I also found different approach of using in Magento core files. Please check my answer above.

Answer (score 1):

Magento2 give possibilities to translate links and use it.
It could be safely done in this way:

```
__('Only registered users can write reviews. Please <a href="%1">Sign in</a> or <a href="%2">create an account</a>', $block->getLoginLink(), $block->getRegisterUrl())
```

where **%1** is **$block->getLoginLink()** and **%2** is **$block->getRegisterUrl()**

BUT for correct showing on the frontend, need to use **escapeHtml** this translation with allowed tags for escaping `$block->escapeHtml(...)`

So, to show url like typical `<a href="">` tag, we need to do the following:

```
$block->escapeHtml(__('Only registered users can write reviews. Please <a href="%1">Sign in</a> or <a href="%2">create an account</a>', $block->getLoginLink(), $block->getRegisterUrl()), ['a'])
```

where add **['a']** tag like allowed tag for escaping.

In translation file (*i18n/en_US.csv*), it should looks like:

```
"Only registered users can write reviews. Please <a href=""%1"">Sign in</a> or <a href=""%2"">create an account</a>","Only registered users can write reviews. Please <a href=""%1"">Sign in</a> or <a href=""%2"">create an account</a>"
```

P.S. I took this example from core file: *vendor/magento/module-review/view/frontend/templates/form.phtml* , so I think, this approach is also valid

Answer (score -1):

Use like this

```
<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Street Address %1', $_i)) ?>
```

or

```
<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Customer address <a href="%s">link</a>!', $block->escapeUrl($this->getBaseUrl().'customer/address/'))) ?>
```

The string in the CSV file should have double quotes:

```
"Customer address <a href=""%s"">link</a>!"
```

Comment: Any html tags should not be in the translation function.

Comment: @jonijones Incorrect. Sometimes you need to translate strings where a link could appear in the middle.

Comment: This isn't correct, you use sprintf() *after* Magento translated the string: `echo sprintf( __('My string with <a href="%s">link</a>') , $myLink )` and the string in the CSV file should have double quotes: "My string with <a href=""%s"">link</a>"

Comment: @DesignbyAdrian, a string should be translated without reference to any HTML tags. You don't translate tags, you translate text output. Also, translation can break tags.

Comment: @jonijones But a link can appear in different places in a sentence depending on language. I know it's wrong, but if the client wants only part of a sentence to be highligted, what's are the options?

Comment: @DesignbyAdrian, I've added the answer how it should look.

Comment: @DesignbyAdrian Thanks, the answer has corrected!